# Set Grouped table view background colour

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, background-color, uicolor

how can i set the background color of a grouped table view to clear color so that is get the image of the underlying Image View.
i tried to set the view color to clear view in the xib
it works fine in case of a normal table view
but doesnt work for a grouped table view
i also tried it programmatically but in vain
is there any work around

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this code for clear the background color of grouped table view..

```
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[backView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[yourTableView setBackgroundView:backView];
```

Thanks..

Comment: thanks but this is what worked for me 
[yourTableView setBackgroundView:nil];